# Cannot close jquery dialog after radiobuttonlist click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using the jquery ui dialog and I've got it set up so that it has a text box and a button.
You basically type something into the text box and click the button, it pulls some values from a database and loads a radiobutton list.  HTML markup looks like this:

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Select Address">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNewUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="search" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFindSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                <asp:Button ID="btnFindSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    onclick="btnFindSearch_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="searchresults" style="width:100%;">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbSearchResults" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    CellSpacing="10" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                    ToolTip="Select an address." 
                    onselectedindexchanged="rbSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

In the code behind I can get the selected value like this:

```
 protected void rbSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = rbSearchResults.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

My issue is I don't know how to close the jquery dialog box AFTER a selection is made from the radio button list.  I tried to do something like this in jquery:

```
  $('#MainContent_rbSearchResults input').click(function () {
       $('#dialog').hide();
   });
```

Even if I throw an alert in there it doesn't display the alert.  If I view page source I see the div container but I don't see the radiobuttonlist, could it be because it is wrapped in an updatepanel?

How can I close the jquery ui dialog after I get a value (a click of the radiobuttonlist)?

## Edit

I tried with this:

```
 protected void rbSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = rbSearchResults.SelectedValue.ToString();
            this.txtShipToName.Text = Label1.Text;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "closedialog", "$(function(){$('#dialog').dialog('close');});", true);
        }
```

And this closes the dialog however my textbox txtShipToName never gets a value.  Even though if I step through the debug I see the value being assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txtShipToName` is not inside the UpdatePanel, that is why it is not holding its value.

To solve this issue you can put `txtShipToName` inside another `UpdatePanel` with UpdateMode set to Conditional and then add this to your code:

```
Label1.Text = rbSearchResults.SelectedValue.ToString();
this.txtShipToName.Text = Label1.Text;
this.theNewUpdatePanel.Update(); //Add this line
```

**EDIT**

As ek_ny stated on his answer, it is better to set UpdateMode to always for the new UpdatePanel and then you don't need to call `Update()` on it.

Comment: Is there any way around this?  I just want to update that txtShipToName with the value selected.  I can see the value in code behind and it assigns it in code behind...

Comment: @oJM86o See my edited answer, you need to put txtShipToName in another UpdatePanel and call Update() on it.

Comment: The issue is this was just an example, i have about 10 fields that need updating based on a selection of the radiobutton.  So I really didnt want to use another updatepanel to do this.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Also if I remove the updatepanel all together I can see the textbox get its value now, but now the jquery dialog box disappears when I click a server side button on that dialog box.  Ugh!!!!

Comment: But If I wrap this whole area in an updatepanel a lot of stuff stops working.

Comment: @oJM86o Maybe if you wrap the whole thing inside the already existing updatePanel, but change its UpdateMode from Conditional to Always. Give it a try...

Comment: Thats what Im talking about can we chat about it so I can show you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10335/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-daniloquio)

Answer (score 1):

For your second issue (Edit part)--- the txtShipName is probably not in the update panel which is being updated. You can put the txtShipName in an UpdatePanel and set it's (the UpdatePanel) UpdateMode to UpdateAlways. Now that you have your dialog working-- this should also cause your text box to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$("#MainContent_rbSearchResult").on("click", "input", function(){
    $('#dialog').hide();
});
```

When you do an ajax call you lost the click handler since html is removed and regenerated inside the update panel. Using `on` method you solve this problem since handlers are re-attached when new controls are created after ajax postback.

Comment: Same issue, but I was able to hide it using my edit above, my only issue is I want to set my textbox value with the value selected from the radio button.  When I debug this in visual studio it shows up correctly assigning the value of label1.text to txtshipToName.text, but immidiately after it the dialog closes no changes are made to the textbox :(, its still empty

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example will be useful
http://jsfiddle.net/prJu7/

Try to use

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close')
```

instead

```
 $('#dialog').hide();
```